# Kundera Redis plugin returns empty list on query

Tags: kundera

I am trying to resolve a problem where I cannot return a list with Kundera query for redis back end. I have problem returning a single entity and no problem persistening entities. However when I try to do a simple select to return a single type it always returns me an empty list.

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
https://raw.github.com/impetus-opensource/Kundera/Kundera-2.0.4/kundera-core/src/test/resources/META-INF/persistence_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">


    <persistence-unit name="redis_pu">
        <provider>com.impetus.kundera.KunderaPersistence</provider>

        <class>com.factory.ng.api.domain.DomainEntity</class>
        <class>com.factory.ng.api.domain.Factory</class>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>

        <properties>
            <property name="kundera.show.query" value="true" />
            <property name="kundera.nodes" value="localhost" />
            <property name="kundera.port" value="6379" />
            <property name="kundera.keyspace" value="RedisK" />
            <property name="kundera.dialect" value="redis" />
            <property name="kundera.client" value="redis" />
            <property name="kundera.client.lookup.class" value="com.impetus.client.redis.RedisClientFactory" />
            <property name="kundera.transaction.resource.class" value="com.impetus.client.redis.RedisTransaction" />
            <property name="kundera.indexer.class" value="com.impetus.client.redis.RedisIndexer" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
    ...
```

Here is the entity that I am trying to retrieve.

```
@Entity
@XmlRootElement
public class Factory extends DomainEntity implements IHasSlots {

    /**
     * Serialization Id
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7829467874878679280L;

    private String name;

    private List<Line> lines;

    public Factory() {
        this(null);
    }

    public Factory(String name) {
        this(name, new ArrayList<Line>());
    }

    public Factory(String name, Collection<Line> lines) {
        this(name, new ArrayList<Line>(lines));
    }
    ...
```

This unit test always ends with an assert error that the list is empty.

```
@Test
public void testList() {
    EntityManagerFactory emFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("redis_pu");
    EntityManager em = emFactory.createEntityManager();
    List<Factory> factories = em.createQuery("SELECT e FROM Factory e").getResultList();
    //Collection<Factory> factories = factoryDao.list();
    Assert.assertTrue(factories.size() > 0);
}
```

Comment: Is the data persisted corresponding to the entity ?

Comment: Once I added the Indexer this problem seems to have gone away. I was in the middle of testing and shortly after the problem worked again. I did find that there were a large number of issues when the parent class of all the entities is a MappedSuperClass that provided the "@Id". This cause quite a few problems with transactions, relationships etc. It works much better now that I have the "@Id" defined in each one of the entities rather than the parent MappedSuperClass.